# How to configure the WildFly messaging-activemq subsystem with JMS to work over https

Tags: jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis, undertow

I am running WildFly 26.1 and have added the `messaging-activemq` subsystem to it. I want to configure it so that I can attach a remote client over `https` transport an send JMS messages back and forth. The way I have configured WildFly seems to work fine, but when I try to attach my client I always get an exception:

```
[01-17 16:06:36] [] Failed to connect to server xx.xxx.xx.227:443
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:882)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:299)
    at com.tpt.common.jmsproxyclient.JMSProxyClient.connect(JMSProxyClient.java:282)
    at com.tpt.gelly.ConnectionNegotiator.establishConnection(ConnectionNegotiator.java:886)
    at com.tpt.gelly.ConnectionNegotiator.negotiateConnection(ConnectionNegotiator.java:1224)
    at com.tpt.gelly.Client.login(Client.java:1254)
    at com.tpt.gelly.Client$MultiLoginRunnable.runTraditional(Client.java:1190)
    at com.tpt.gelly.Client$MultiLoginRunnable.run(Client.java:1135)
    at com.tpt.ui.common.TPRunnable.run(TPRunnable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:708)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:880)
    ... 13 more
```

If the client tries to connect over `http` everything works, but I am unable to figure out what is needed to get a connection over `https`. I would like to know how I configure ActiveMQ Artemis and Undertow correctly and what properties must be set in the client application to make the connection over `https`. I would also like to know where I can find some good documentation for both ActiveMQ Artemis and Undertow configuration as well as ActiveMQ Artemis client connector properties.

The WildFly `standalone.xml` configuration for ActiveMQ Artemis connectors and acceptors that I am using is:

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.1">
            <server name="default">

                <!--  HTTPS connector/acceptor/factory -->
                <http-connector name="https-connector" socket-binding="https" endpoint="https-acceptor">
                    <param name="sslEnabled" value="true"/> 
                </http-connector>
                <http-acceptor name="https-acceptor" http-listener="https"/>
                <connection-factory name="HttpsRemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/HttpsRemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="https-connector"/>

                <!--  HTTPS throughput connector/acceptor -->
                <http-connector name="https-connector-throughput" socket-binding="https" endpoint="https-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="sslEnabled" value="true"/> 
                </http-connector>
                <http-acceptor name="https-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="https">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

The Undertow configuration for `http` & `https` in that same file is:

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:12.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>            
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="smsSSC" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <http-invoker http-authentication-factory="application-http-authentication"/>
                </host>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

The client code trying to connect remotely is below. I don't use JNDI because we don't want to open up another port externally. The property name constants come from `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.TransportConstants`

```java
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(HTTP_UPGRADE_ENDPOINT_PROP_NAME, "https-acceptor");
    params.put(ACTIVEMQ_SERVER_NAME, "default");
    params.put(HTTP_UPGRADE_ENABLED_PROP_NAME, true);
    params.put(PORT_PROP_NAME, 443);
    params.put(HOST_PROP_NAME, "host");
    params.put(SSL_ENABLED_PROP_NAME, true);
    TransportConfiguration transport = new TransportConfiguration("org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory", params);
    return ActiveMQJMSClient.createConnectionFactoryWithoutHA(JMSFactoryType.CF, transport);
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem, but the `https` `socket-binding` is `8443` in the WildFly configuration and we use `sbin/iptables` to reroute port `443` to `8443` and then block `8443` from external access using `/sbin/iptables\`:

```bash
      /sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport https -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
      # any iptables cmds with 'mark' are to keep the local port closed outside
      /sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8443 -j MARK --set-mark 1
      /sbin/ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8443 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Comment: Can you connect to 8443 locally so we can rule out or not the iptables configuration ?

Comment: I used curl to check a https connection on port 8443 and it worked. I can also use https remotely so it is connecting to port 443 properly

Comment: Sorry I wan't clear: I meant connecting using your code

Comment: No, but that is expected as we blocked access to port 8443 from external access. I could not access our web app on port 8443 either. I'll try to see how I might turn the blocking of that port off and check again.

Comment: After disabling the external block on port 8443 I still get the same error, even though I can access the web app on that port now

Comment: Did you try setting  <param name="sslEnabled" value="true"/> on your http acceptor ?

Comment: I did, and that did not work either. I also added all of the key store and trust store properties as well, still did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            <http-connector name="https-connector" socket-binding="https" endpoint="https-acceptor">
                <param name="enabled-protocols" value="TLSv1.2"/>
                <param name="keyStoreType" value="JKS"/>
                <param name="trustStorePassword" value="artemisexample"/>
                <param name="verify-host" value="false"/>
                <param name="keyStorePassword" value="artemisexample"/>
                <param name="trustStorePath" value="${some_path}/cacerts"/>
                <param name="trustStoreType" value="PKCS12"/>
                <param name="ssl-enabled" value="true"/>
                <param name="keyStorePath" value="${some_path}/artemis.example.keystore"/>
            </http-connector>
```

This is a sample connector ^^ for WildFly to an https-acceptor with simple configuration:

```
<http-acceptor name="https-acceptor" http-listener="undertow-https"/>
```

and

```
<https-listener name="undertow-https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="server-ssl-context"/>
```

This looks very close to what you are doing

Comment: Since we are not using JNDI to retrieve the connector from the server, I added verifyHost property with a value of false and all of the trust store properties to the client and it worked! Thank you! 

When looking back through the activemq artemis documentation (link below) it said that verifyHost is false. Do you  know if wildfly is turning it on?
https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.0.0/configuring-transports.html

Comment: If you are not using your connector on your wildfly server, would keyStoreParth and trustStorePath be referencing paths on the client machine or host? If they are referencing the file on the host, how does that work on the client? Or is your client running on the same machine?

Comment: The connector provides the client with the details on how to set up the connection: the path are for the client not on the server. The server configuration is in the acceptor.